# Conditional repeat of report header in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I have a crystal report and I am trying to display the the data in multiple columns.

For that I have done **Format using Multiple Columns** method

My report structure is as follows

**page1**

```
Val1  Val2      Val1  Val2      Val1  Val2 
 A1     A2       D1    D2        G1    G2
 B1     B2       E1    E2        H1    H2
 C1     C2       F1    F2        I1    I2
```

and on **page 2**

```
Val1  Val2      Val1  Val2      Val1  Val2 
 J1     J2       
 K1     K2       
 L1     L2
```

I have added headers manually i.e(Val1,Val2)

My question is how can I avoid columns Val1 and Val2 when there is no data displayed below it(like **page2**)

I am using VS 2010 and CR

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Although this was asked earlier but,  someone might have this doubt as well in near future:
There is an option of suppress on textobject when we choose Format Object by right clicking on the same, against that option there is a symbol to specify the formula where you can specify the condition to hide and show etc.

```
if(condition...) then true 
else false
```